# How to run TestCafe tool scripts using particular grouping - smoke, regression, etc.? What would be the proper syntax of cmd?

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, regression-testing, testcafe, smoke-testing

I'm trying to find the best way of How to run TestCafe tool scripts using particular grouping - smoke, regression, etc.? What would be the proper syntax of cmd?
WE have script with fixture and think to use it for grouping.All  I need to find out the answer is it is possible and what would be the correct cmd for that.
THanks for the reply, 
Alex

Answer (score 2):

In order to run a subset of Fixtures/Tests (i.e. 'Smoke'), you can now use the `.meta({key: 'value', key2: 'value2'})` option for both the Fixture and the Test objects.

Example:

```
test
    .meta({smoke: true, feature: true})
```

or

```
fixture
    .meta('crud': 'read'})
```

Then, when running from the command line, pass `--test-meta key=value` or `--fixture-meta key=value` options now, as mentioned [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#specifying-testing-metadata)

And again in the [Enhancements documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/blog/testcafe-v0-23-1-released.html)

Comment: This is my first answer to a SO question, so I'm happy to receive feedback on how to improve it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's a very good solution for TestCafe versions starting from 0.23.1.

Answer (score 1):

Please use "[fixture](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#fixtures)" to group test. To filter run fixtures, use the following options:

-F or [--fixture-grep](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-f-pattern---fixture-grep-pattern) patern

-t or [--test](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-t-name---test-name) name

-f or [--fixture](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-f-name---fixture-name) name

Comment: Thank you very much, Marion!

Comment: You are welcome! Would you please mark the Answer as Solution?